# Flutter Firebase Firestore Web App with REST API

Tags: firebase, flutter, rest

I have built a flutter web app which I deploy to the firebase hosting and that uses firebase firestore as backend solution.
Now I want to enable users to use a REST API to add entries to the database. Can anyone point me to a good Tutorial thats specific to this use case? I have not implemented a REST API before and get lost in the different types how this can be setup (cloud functions, node.js, etc.).

Thanks in advance!
timo

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api do read more firestore api

Comment: Google Cloud Tech youtube channel has good tutorials, watch "Hosting a REST API with a Cloud Firestore backend"